# Appium detects the WindowElements only 30% of the times

Tags: c#, wpf, appium, winappdriver

I currently work with C# with AppWinDriver and Appium for automated tests for WPF, but in the project app that i work, it is detected correctly sometimes, others times work good and some times open the page but doesn't detect the WindowsElements of the app.

Any idea on the root cause of the issue or a solution or workaround?

Code:

```cs
AppiumOptions desiredCapabilities = new AppiumOptions();
desiredCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("app",app);
desiredCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("createSessionTimeout", "60000");
desiredCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("newCommandTimeout", "60000");
desiredCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Windows");
desiredCapabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
```

Comment: How is it possible to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Between your Asserts add an Thread.Sleep(~2000) in order to trigger detects that Assert inside that 30% scope of time